# Find device type iPhone 4 or iPhone5 not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
            //NSLog(@"phonesize%@",result);
        if(result.height > 500){
                NSLog(@"iPhone 5");      
        }
        else{
                NSLog(@"iPhone 4");

            }
    }
```

My Mac OS is 10.7.2 and Xcode 4.5.2.I used above code to find device is iPhone 4 or iPhone 5
It is giving iPhone4 when i uses iPhone5.I did set launch image and icon image. Is there anything else i missed out?

Comment: Where do you call this code?

Comment: i call this code in viewwillappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a PNG file named `Default-568h@2x.png` in your project.

Comment: it was wrong there.thanks for ur answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to scale the `result` you got as per the screen's scale `scale` and then check ...

```
 if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector(scale)]) {
            CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
            CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

        if(result.height == 960) {
            NSLog(@"iPhone 4");
        }
        if(result.height == 1136) {
            NSLog(@"iPhone 5");
        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Standard Resolution");
    }
}
```

Comment: as result.height is a float it is better not to use == in a comparison, rather use > or <

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead its tested.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
      //device is iPhone

      CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
      if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
        //device is iphone 5
        //add storyboard/Xib that have large screen (320*568)
      } else {
          //device is iphone 4
          //add story board/Xib that have small screen (320*480)

      }

    }
else
    {
      //device is iPad
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
      CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
      if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) 
      {
         //iphone 5

      else 
      {

        //iphone 4


      }
   }
else
    {
      //iPad
    }
```

Try this one might be helpful to you...